# enumerate in python over a list with an index?

Tags: python, list, enumerate

I have been asked what the output of this function call would be:
enumerate([6, 'one', 'a'], 3)[1]

The python interpreter says its an error because its not scriptable and if you take away the index call it just returns an enumerate function 
Does anyone know what this would return, assuming it would work?

Comment: `The python interpreter says its an error`. This would happen for all of us (assuming we're all using python 3+). In python2 (which you shouldn't use because it is no longer supported), the answer is `(4, 'one')`

Comment: Just read about [enumerate](https://realpython.com/python-enumerate/) function. It is really much faster and more productive than writing a question on SO.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget it's the same error in python2

Answer (score 1):

Try evaluating `list(enumerate([6, 'one', 'a'], 3))[1]`.